# bibunits: cannot get it to work (no bu1 produced)

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, auxiliary-files, bibunits

I am trying to use the package `bibunits` to have separate bibliographies for sections, chapters,...

I am using TeXShop on a Mac, and I just recently installed "TeX Live 2012".
I downloaded the file `bibunits.sty` and put it in the same folder as the files I want to compile.
(I hope this is the best thing to do)

I followed the introduction by Thorsten Hansen, I used this file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibunits}

\begin{document}
\begin{bibunit}[plain]
References to the \TeX book \cite{Knuth:1991}
and to Lamport’s \LaTeX\ book, 
which appears only in the references\nocite{Lamport:1994}.
\putbib[lit]
\end{bibunit}

\begin{bibunit}[alpha]
A new bibunit with a different style
and a cite of a Postscript tutorial.
\end{bibunit}
\end{document}
```

However, no "bu1" or "bu2" is produced when I LaTeX this maintex-file.
Instead, I get `maintex.1.aux` and `maintex.2.aux`, and then I simply do not know what to do next.  I tried BibTex-ing and LaTex-ing all files several times, but I don't get any references in my pdf, just a "?".

Could you tell me what I am probably doing wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Firstly, it should not be necessary to download `bibunits` yourself, as it is already a part of TeXlive.  I suggest you remove the local copy of the style.  Secondly, your example compiles fine for me and produces `bu1.aux`; there is no `bu2.aux` as you have no citations in that section.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the bibunits.sty file, and only then was he willing to produce bu1.aux
If I use a terminal and type "bibtex bu1.aux", then it works, but is it possible to "BibTex" bu1.auw in TexShop itself?

Comment: Have a look at the "Tips & Tricks" help file, in particular section 6.1 discussing the "pdflatexmk" engine.  This runs "latexmk" that will cope with the necessary "bibtex" invocations etc.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your distribution TeXlive already includes `bibunits.sty`, so it is best to work with that version, rather than a local copy (which may not have been correctly set up).  Just make sure your distribution is up-to-date (in this case via `sudo tlmgr update --all` in a terminal), and remove the local style file.  Running your code on the standard distribution through `pdflatex` then produces `bu1.aux` as expected; there is no `bu2.aux` as you have no citations in that section.

Secondly, have a look section 6.1 of the "Tips & Trikcs" help file that comes with TexShop.  There it will you tell you how to invoke the `pdflatexmk` engine, which will take care of the full compilation process, including running `bibtex` on the correct files, for you.